# I want to add a background color between two background images

Tags: html, css, background-image

Does anyone have an idea how to fill the middle with the same color as the background image?

```
#first-illustration {
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  background:url("../images/bg-section-top-desktop-1.svg") top, url("../images/bg-section-bottom-desktop-1.svg") bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

This is how it appears [image: 1]

Comment: How about `background-color: #f6fbff`?

Comment: there are various tools you can download to extract the HEX color on pages, if you were having trouble with identifying the color I would suggest to look for a chrome extenssion tool called eyedropper there are various ones, these can help you extract the colors from images or anything on the browser you want to copy the shade of.

Comment: @user3738870 The images are probably transparent, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a background gradient with hard transitions:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0%, transparent 15%, #f6fbff 15%, #f6fbff 90%, transparent 90%), url(..), url(..);
```

But that won't be responsive out of the box, involves tweaking and possibly media queries.

A better way IMHO is to move the background images to the `before` and `after` pseudo elements, and set their [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) to that of the images:

```
.illustration {
    background: #f6fbff;
    /* ... */
}

.illustration::before, .illustration::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background: no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
}
.illustration::before {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-section-top-desktop-1.svg");
    aspect-ratio: 10 / 1;
}
.illustration::after {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-section-bottom-desktop-1.svg");
    aspect-ratio: 12 / 2;
}
```